# Can I using springboot application with hikariCP on JBoss WAS?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, datasource, hikaricp, connection-pool

I implemented springboot application using hikari CP for database connection pooling. And now I need to deploy the application to the Jboss EAP server which has datasources configuration with connection pool. what happen if i deploy the application on the WAS? would Hikari CP manages connections based on the WAS's datasource connection pool? or would size of connection pool be just added? (hikariCP pool size + jboss datasource pool size)
Is it common to use both application level connection pool and WAS connection pool at the same time? Or should I remove hikari CP from application before deploy it to jboss?

as i check in the APM tool connection size seems be added (hikariCP pool size + jboss datasource pool size). but i'm not sure is it normal. i expected hikari CP would work based on the WAS connection pool size.

Comment: Depends on your configuration. If you specify the `jndi-name` it will use the JBOSS configured one. If you keep running with the `spring.datasource.url` etc. it will use the application `HikariCP`. It will not combine the two in whatever way.

Comment: @M.Deinum
Thanks for the comments. If i use jndi-name, do i need to set hikari cp max pool size same as the one from jboss datasource?

Comment: As stated if you use jndi-name it will use the one from jboss. All other things will be ignored.